# Java Web development in eclipse 

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am building a web application using java servlets and jsp.
Every thing is working fine but I can't see the source code of the files like
HttpServlet from my eclipse IDE.
I think I need to download J2EE sdk. Right ??
Please tell the steps

Thank you all

Comment: you can download source code from apache site and attach it to the jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cool tool called jad that will do this for you.

Here's a link that explains how to install it:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/